# Chuck Steak or Chuck Roast for Stew

Tags: beef

I have 4+ lbs of beef chuck steak in my freezer. I was wondering if I could use those to make beef stew, or if I would be better off with beef chuck roast. The steaks are 1-1 1/4" thick, frozen. Thank you!

Comment: I like the idea of using what you have.   Eventually it is going to get freezer burn and not be as good.  Stew is a great destiny for freezer meet.

Answer (score 3):

A chuck steak is simply cut into slices more ideal for grilling whereas a roast is left in larger thicker shapes more ideal for roasting. Once you break them down into stew shape either is viable.

Comment: Exactly, it's the same meat.

Comment: Though steaks are often priced higher because of the extra labor involved.

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker sometimes, but when cleaning out your freezer such concerns aren't as important.